# multiple checkbox in single column for TbExtendedGridView in yii 1.1

Tags: checkbox, yii

I have used table extended grid view in my form.I want to add multiple check-boxes in a single column?What is the solution?
I have used single checkbox in a column.My code is

```
 array(  'id' => 'selectedIds','class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn', 
         'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>25,),
          'selectableRows'=>2,
        // 'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => array('name' => 'idList[]'),
            'name'=>'idList[]'
            ),
```

Comment: What have you already tried?